# Make a phone call in Windows 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-8.1, phone-call

To make a phone call in Windows Phone 8.1 I have to do the following:

```
Windows.ApplicationModel.Calls.ShowPhoneCallUI(number, name);
```

But in Windows 8.1 app there is no class `PhoneCallManager` in `Windows.ApplicationModel.Calls` namespace. Is there any way to make a phone call in Windows 8.1 store app?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just googled for you and found that link.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.calls.phonecallmanager.aspx

Always try to stay on the newest stand in your programming network. I also found that:

> Windows Phone 8.1 [Windows Runtime apps only]

is compatible to run

`public static void ShowPhoneCallUI(
  string phoneNumber, 
  string displayName
)`

I think that microsoft is still updating their classes to 8.1 but you would be able to use already some namespaces.

Comment: Unlockedluca, thanks for your answer. I have just read this docs.  `Windows.ApplicationModel.Calls` is supported on Windows 8.1. It is not clear why `PhoneCallManager` is not supported. I thought that there is an another way to make a phone call on Win different from WinPhone as well as many other things.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm thinking, they are updating their API's for Win 8.1 so you need to pause your project or work with a Win 8 device :) 
If that solved your question you can mark is as answer :)

Answer (score 0):

On Windows Phone (!) you can either use

```
var phoneCallTask = new PhoneCallTask 
{ 
    PhoneNumber = number,
    DisplayName = "The Name goes here" 
};

phoneCallTask.Show();
```

or

```
Windows.ApplicationModel.Calls.PhoneCallManager.ShowPhoneCallUI(number, "The Name goes here");
```

Maybe you are simply missing an assembly reference?

Comment: Thanks for answer. That works only on WinPhone, but the problem is to do the same on Windows 8.1. There are no such classes and methods.

Comment: You cannot call a phone number on a regular Windows system.

Comment: Krumelur, I think it is possible on Windows tablet with sim